# how to stop alarm running ant controlled

Tags: android, android-alarms

the source code here........

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmAppActivity.this, 0, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT );
                  //Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmAppActivity.this, AlarmService.class);
               //   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmAppActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);


Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
System.out.println("in   alendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY "+Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
// calendar.setTimeInMillis(hour);
                            //calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
// calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
System.out.println("in   alarmManager.set(AlarmMana) "+calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the [`cancel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) method with this pending intent:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```